# TextCriteria with diacriticSensitive. Spring Data MongoDB 1.10.9

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to create a search in my MongoDB database to search the "name" field without taking into account the accents

I need to create an index in the field:

// create index

```
@Indexed
@Field("nombre")
private String nombre;
```

Check in the BBDD that it is created correctly:

```
db.empleado_bk.getIndexes();

{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "nombre" : 1
    },
    "name" : "nombre",
    "ns" : "elser2.empleado_bk"
}
```

I modify my repository to search in text without taking accents into account

```
if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(dtoFilter.getNombre())) {
query.addCriteria(TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().diacriticSensitive(true).matching("nombre"));
}
```

But when looking for that field, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 27 and error message 'text index required for $text query'
```

Can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong if I need to do something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You applied a standard index with `@Indexed`. To apply a text search index, you need to use `@TextIndexed`.